# Moving a char around a 2D array to a location C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am creating a program that mimic's planes flying around. I currently have a 2D array that prints nicely. What I want is to set the planes at user defined locations and have them all fly around to a destination the user defines. For instance they can be set at any point on a 10x10 grid and then all fly to a defined location and then fly back to where they started.

This is the 2D grid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void printLine(){ std::cout << "--------------------------------------------
-------" << std::endl; }

int main(){

const int WIDTH = 10;
const int LENGTH = 10;
char chars[WIDTH][LENGTH] = {};
//chars[0][0] = 'P';
//chars[4][4] = 'P';

printLine();
for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i){

    for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; ++j){

    std::cout << "|" << std::setw(5) << chars[i][j] << std::setw(5) << ' ';

    }

   std::cout << "|" << std::endl;
   printLine();

 }

 return 0;

}
```

I know I need to retrieve the location of the planes by scanning for user input with std::cin but I am confused on what the best approach is to have the planes move and then re-print that 2D grid to watch them move around in terminal. I do not need to it be live in terminal every time a plane moves the array can just be reprinted. I initially thought just to try and match the location of the plane to the destination and keep incriminating (X,Y) value until they match but I am unsure how to properly tackle that in code that isn't just a hacky work around. I would also would like to try and avoid collisions but I think getting a move function to work would be the first step then work on collisions. If anyone has any advice they could give me on how to structure the code for what I described above that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm always nervous when I see C++ in the topic list but the code isn't object oriented. If you can solve the problem in C, then there's no point using the C++ compiller.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this will be using a graph, then you could find a path between the current position of the plane and the destination.